# bedrock wordpress, Nginx proxy & node.js

Tags: node.js, wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, trellis

Problem: a server behind proxy unreachable for api listening port 3050 with bedrock wordpress.

I had deployed wordpress with [Trellis](https://roots.io/) to my VMs. Everything is up and running perfectly.
The wordpress site is accessible to the http://example.com but it won't able access through IP address like http://192.168.1.157

I had setup a node api that listening on port 3050. but when I try to browse/curl it with http://192.168.1.157:3050 or http://192.168.1.157/api

Chrome is return: This site can’t be reached ; ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I only able to reach the site with http://example.com/api

I have an Nginx reverse proxy that helps me route to my Proxmox VMs.

Here are the routing rules written on my reverse proxy:

```
location ~* /api/ {
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.157:3050;
}
```

I am looking for a way, that my Trellis Wordpress can be accessed through http://192.168.1.157 . I think it will help me solve the problem.

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks